# HTML document will not read external CSS?

Tags: html, css, youtube, blogs

I have tried many things but cannot get these two documents to work together. I am sure the CSS file is linked correctly with the correct file name. I'm attempting this after watching this YouTube video tutorial below on coding a blog. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24QmGjcqIiw

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new 1.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            </head>
            <body>
                    <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="header">
                    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <div class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <p>Testing Testing 123...</p>
                </div>

                <div class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <p>Testing Testing 123...</p>
                </div>

                <div class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <p>Testing Testing 123...</p>
                </div>

                <div class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <p>Testing Testing 123...</p>
                </div>

                <div class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <p>Testing Testing 123...</p>
                </div>

            </div>          
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now here's the CSS:

```
*{

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body{
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#000000;
    }
    wrapper{
            width: 80px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
    }
    #header 

    {
        background-color:#cZazqqcccccaccccc;
        height:800px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }


    #.post
    {
        background-color:#ffffff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }
```

Comment: Try `new1.css` instead of `new 1.css`. Both files (.html and .css) need to be in the same folder.

Comment: Yeah...that space will throw it off for sure.

Comment: Besides the location of the CSS file relative to your HTML file, some of your CSS is suspect. For example, `#.post` isn't valid. The header background color of `#cZazqqcccccaccccc` is a weird value....

Comment: Thanks, Fixed the mistakes. Am noticing it works perfectly on the mac I coded this on but when I move it over to a windows machine that's where the problems arise. File locations and names are definitely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the 2 most common culprits:

1. Incorrect filename
2. Incorrect file location

If your filename is definitely correct, go straight to 2. It is considered best practice to avoid spaces, even though browsers should be able to read them as @zzzzBov points out.

There's 3 main ways you can reference your files:

- a direct link to the file, without specifying a path
- a relative link, which points to your file *relative* to where the file requesting it is located
- an absolute link, which specifies a complete file path from a domain or a hard drive

And if you file structure (how you've organised all your stuff) looks like this:

```
public_html
    L css
        L myStyles.css
    L index.html
    L aboutMySite.html
```

Your links inside `index.html` and `aboutMySite.html` would look like this:

- direct link: `/css/myStyles.css` (the first `/` represents the root directory, or the highest level folder in which your site lives)
- relative link: `../css/myStyles.css`
- absolute link: `www.mysite.com/css/myStyles.css`

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using space characters in your filenames.

Rename `new 1.css` to `new1.css` (make sure both the reference and the actual filename match) and make sure all CSS files are in the same folder as your HTML file since you are not specifying any path.

If you really wish to use the space character (an invalid character for URIs), encode them with `%20`, but it's a lot simpler to avoid them.

Comment: spaces aren't a problem, although they should be correctly encoded as `new%201.css` in the `[href]` attribute.

Comment: Hence the "avoid" wording to keep it simple.

Comment: browsers will still work just fine if you don't correctly escape the space character.